# Saving page in wordpress adds <a href>

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have the following code...

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <a href="/category/newsroom">
        <div class="resource-list">
            <div class="resource-list-content">
                <h3>Newsroom</h3>
                <p class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean semper volutpat tellus non faucibus.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

But when I save it its adds an extra  as per the below which I dont want..

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <a href="/category/newsroom">
        <div class="resource-list">
            <div class="resource-list-content">
                <h3>Newsroom</h3>
                <p class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean semper volutpat tellus non faucibus.</p>
           </div>
       </div>
    </a>
    <a href="/category/newsroom"></a>
</div>
```

How do I go about removing this from happening, I presume something in functions.php?

Comment: I think this might be rather part of the client-side editor functionality. Before HTML5, `a` was not allowed to contain block-level elements such as `div`, so in such cases, some “auto correction” of what is considered faulty HTML might get applied (yes, the result would still be faulty by that measure though.) Is this a very outdated WP version, by any chance?

Comment: Which page template is it? What is in your `functions.php`?

Comment: I am using blank slate and have added just a short bit of PHP to prevent WP adding Br tags. Also I believe it is updated to the recent version of WP.

Comment: As per CRroe, it does seem like something that is trying to 'fix' the html code.  I ran a quick check on https://wpautop.anmari.com/  but that does not do that to your html.  It does however trigger the trailing </p> problme in wpautop.